# Isomorphic Homology implies Isomorphic Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

If two complexes have isomorphic integral homology, do the dual complexes have isomorphic integral cohomology? I can also assume that the homology, cohomology are finitely-generated abelian groups.

The question I really care about is the following. If two simply-connected spaces (manifolds) have isomorphic integral homology, does that imply that they have isomorphic integral cohomology? Clearly this is true over fields by the universal coefficient theorem. Note that I am not assuming that the isomorphism is induced by a map of spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true over $\mathbb{Z}$ by the universal coefficient theorem over $\mathbb{Z}$.

For the question with "homology" and "cohomology" switched see [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268593/is-homology-determined-by-cohomology).