# if $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Q})=0$ and $\operatorname{Ext}(A,\mathbb{Z}_p)=\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z}_p)=0$ implies $A=0$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I want to prove that

> If $A$ is an abelian group such that
>   $$\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Q})=0$$ 
>   and,
>   $$\text{Ext}(A,\mathbb{Z}_p)=\text{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z}_p)=0  \text{ for every prime } p$$ 
>   then $A=0$.

I want to follow the reasoning in the response of

[Does trivial cohomology imply trivial homology? Does $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb Z) = \operatorname{Ext}^1(A, \mathbb Z) = 0$ imply $A = 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734222/does-trivial-cohomology-imply-trivial-homology-does-operatornamehoma-math?rq=1)

and to do that I have to show that $\text{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z})=0$ and $\text{Ext}(A,\mathbb{Z})=0$.

I have not been able to do such a thing. But from the exact sequences of $\text{Ext}$ it is easy to deduce that $\text{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z})=0$ and that $\text{Ext}(A,\mathbb{Z})$ is a torsionfree divisibility group. From this two conclusions it is possible to deduce that $A$ is a torsionfree divisibility group but I could not reach $A=0$.

Any advice?

PD: This problem appears in Hatcher in a more topological way.

Comment: Can you please explicitly specify what you mean by $\mathbb{Z}_p$? Is it the cyclic group with $p$ elements or is it the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $p$? That makes a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{Ext}(-,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ turns injections into surjections,  $\operatorname{Ext}(B,\mathbb{Z}_p)=0$ for every subgroup $B\subseteq A$.  In particular, this means $A$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Taken over all primes $p$, this means that $A$ is torsion-free.

Since $A$ is torsion-free, the canonical map $i:A\to A\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ is injective.  If $A$ were nonzero, then for any nonzero element $a\in A$ we could get a homomorphism $A\otimes\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ which is nonzero on $i(a)$, since $A\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.  This is impossible since $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Q})=0$, so we must have $A=0$.

(Note that the assumption that $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z}_p)=0$ is not needed.)